# Fill an array of objects with some default object

Tags: javascript, lodash.js

I have an array of objects. Whatever may be the size of this array, I need to ensure the size of the array as `n` using a default object.

```
 function fillRemaining(arr, n) {
        var defaultObject = {'id' : 0, 'name' : ''};
        var temp = 0;
        while(arr.length + temp < n ) {
           var template = $.extend({}, defaultObject);
           template.id = new Date().getTime();
           arr.push(defaultObject);
           temp++;
        }
    }
```

Is there a better method of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few ways this can be improved.

First, you are creating the `template` variable as a copy of the `defaultObject`, but then you are inserting `defaultObject` rather than `template`. I am going to assume this is a bug.

I would also say that there is not a big reason why you should have a `defaultObject`, then create and modify a copy to add. Just create objects on the fly.

Second, you are using a `while` loop, but constructing it like a `for` loop (loop variable, incremented every iteration). You actually don't even use the loop variable, so it can be removed completely. There is also a second potential bug where you are checking against `arr.length + temp` in your conditional, but `arr.length` increases every time you add an element to the array, so you are counting by 2's instead of by 1's.

Lastly, the name `fillRemaining` does not clearly describe what the function is supposed to do. Since it is padding onto the end of the array, perhaps `padArrayWithDefault` or something similar might be more descriptive.

Here's what I would suggest:

```
function padArrayWithDefault(arr, n) {
    while(arr.length < n) {
        arr.push({
            "id": new Date().getTime(),
            "name": ""
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a generic approach, using a callback to define what the "default" value should be:

```
function padArray(array, length, callback) {
  while(array.length < length) {
    array.push(callback());
  }
}
```

In your case, you'd use it like so:

```
padArray(someArray, 42, function () {
  return { id: Date.now(), name: "" };
});
```

Note: `Date.now()` [is supported in modern runtimes](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Date.now), but not in some older ones (click "show obsolete browsers" to see). But you can always use `(new Date).getTime()` like you are now.

---

In terms of code review:

- The `arr.length + temp < n` *doesn't actually work*, as far as I can tell. When you do `arr.push()`, the array's length increases, but you also increment `temp`. So your loop will run half as many times as you intend.
- Your code - like mine above - may trigger an infinite loop if the `arr` argument (`array` in my code) isn't an array. E.g. if `arr.length` is undefined the `while`-condition will never be true. So you may want to check for that.
- You're using a default object that you're then "cloning" using `extend`. Two things: 1) given how simple it is, just write it like above instead of cloning, 2) `extend` doesn't do a "deep" clone, so if any of the properties are themselves mutable objects, there'll just be references to the same instance copied all over.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is better, but might be more flexible to have a parameter for a factory function that creates the objects you're filling the `Array` with.

I also added `from` and `to` parameters so subsections can be replaced instead of just the last `n` elements.

```js
function replace(arr, factory, from, to) {
    var i = from;
    if (!from) {
        i = 0;
    } else if (from < 0) {
        i = arr.length + from;
    }
    if (to < 0) {
        to = arr.length + to;
    } else if (to == null) {
        to = arr.length;
    }
    for (; i < to; i++) {
        arr[i] = factory();
    }
}
```

Using it:

```js
var arr;

// making test arrays
function mkArr() {
    return 'a b c d e f g h i'.split(' ');
}

// the factory function for the new values
function makeDefault() {
    return {
        id: +new Date(),
        name: ''
    };
}

// to replace all values in `arr`
arr = mkArr();
replace(arr, makeDefault);

// to replace the last 3 values
arr = mkArr();
replace(arr, makeDefault, -3);

// everything but the first two values
arr = mkArr();
replace(arr, makeDefault, 2);

// replace the second, third and fourth values
arr = mkArr();
replace(arr, makeDefault, 1, 4);
```

A jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atca3xpy/

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure if this is the proper forum for this question. But if I understand correctly, you're trying to create an array that is prefilled with a default object.

If this is the case:

You could simplify by calling the Array constructor with n and then just map over it.

```
function Fill(n, _default) {
   return Array.apply(null,Array(n)).map(function (val) {  
     return _default || { };
   });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the down-vote, but there are a few syntax errors and it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/6y4shces/

Comment: My bad, I'm sorry about that. I've added some corrections.